# Referencing xUnit testing project to Console app by using .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, testing, xunit

I created Console app and xUnit test projects by using .NET 6. Then referenced testing project to project file and buit both of them. However I couldn't import namespaces of project file inside the testing project file. How to solve this problem?

By the way, I use Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Can you provide an image showing your solution and project structure with their dependencies?

Comment: Are your classes by any chance `internal`?